# Convert node ID from string to integer

Tags: 8, nodes

Retrieve a node based on condition:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
->condition('title', 'my node title');
$nid = $query->execute();
```

The result of $nid is the correct node ID but the format is a string, (es: "123")

When I want to load the node by its ID, I write:

```
$node_id = Node::load($nid);
```

Doing this, the result I get is NULL because the variable $nid is holding a string (not integer).
If I write the code like this:

```
$node_id = Node::load(123);
```

I get the node loaded.

How can I convert the variable string ($nid) as an integer ?
I tried:

```
$nid_int = (int) $nid;
$node_id = Node::load($nid_int);
```

also I tried:

```
$nid_int = intval($nid);
$node_id = Node::load($nid_int);
```

But I alwas get result NULL

Thanks for your help

Comment: The result of your entity query is not a node id but an array of ids. That's why your load doesn't work. There's no problem with using a string node ID in a load.

Comment: (not 100% sure) but could there be a possibility your query contains more than just one result? So, you might be trying to load multiple nodes in as a parameter. I could be wrong, just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `$query->execute();` return an array of key/value like `[KEY => nid1]`:
if you are sure you have only one node with that tittle you should get the first element of the array it's your nid try with:

```
 $query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('type', 'my_content_type')
  ->condition('title', 'my node title');
$nids = $query->execute();
// Get the nid in the array.
$nid = reset($nids);
$node = Node::load($nid);
```